# How to convert list of list binary into list of decimal?

Tags: python, arrays, list

LIST OF LIST BIN DIVIDED INTO 8 :  [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]

the output I want is:

[101, 119]

Comment: @Shmack It was probably deleted because it was syntactically flawed

Comment: @Cobra well I didn't get a long enough glance at it, but it looked good.

Comment: @Schmack I can still see the original post. Trust me, it's broken

Answer (score 2):

This is more complex but significantly faster than any kind of string manipulation as it's essentially just integer arithmetic.

```
from timeit import timeit

lob = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]

def v1():
    result = []
    for e in lob:
        r = 0
        for _e in e:
            r = r * 2 + _e
        result.append(r)
    return result

def v2():
    return [int(''.join([str(y) for y in x]), 2) for x in lob]

assert v1() == v2()

for func in v1, v2:
    print(func.__name__, timeit(func))
```

**Output:**

```
v1 0.6906622060014342
v2 2.173182999999881
```

Comment: Are you sure this will be *significantly* faster?

Comment: @user56700 See edit. Performance will vary depending on your system's capability

Comment: Thank you, now I can see that it's faster, but can you elaborate why that might be? I cannot seem to figure out why. Why is `int()` so slow as a build in function?

Comment: @user56700 You need to break down the "string" version into its component parts. You convert each int to a str. You build a list. You join that list. You then convert the resultant str to int. My version is essentially just integer arithmetic

Comment: Thank you so much! Maybe you should add some explanation to the answer too for others. :)

Comment: no need to reverse it though: `for bit in e: r = (r << 1) | bit`

Comment: @gog Of course. I shouldn't try writing code when I'm half asleep. Edited accordingly. I find that on my machine (Python 3.11.0 on 3 GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W), simply multiplying by 2 is faster than bit-shifting. Thank you